# homebrew-services, password store, and python

Tags: python, homebrew

I'm trying to use `homebrew-services` to grab some passwords from [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/). So far I have this. But it doesn't work if I ran it through [`homebrew-services`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services). If I just manually execute it then it works fine.

```py
import subprocess
file = open('/tmp/test.log', 'w');
output = subprocess.check_output(['pass', 'foo']).strip()
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

I was trying to use this to retrieve the password for offlineimap so I was testing using [this `plist`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/offlineimap.rb#L30).

Thanks!

Comment: Pleas define "doesn't work".  Error messages?  Traceback?  Wrong output?  What happens?

Comment: Ah crap sorry. I missed that. There are no error messages. It just doesn't write the output of the file at all. Unfortunately I don't think `pass` has any logs of some sort. After investigating some more, It looks like the issue is that `pass` is not able to connect to `gpg-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X users are not allowed to use `/tmp`, you need to use `mktemp` in order to get a path to a temporary files.

Yep, your user temp directory is not under /tmp on OS X.

Do not ever assume that `/tmp` can be used, that's why mktemp exists.